# Should the 'Recent Reviewers' section in Review Queues be replaced with something more useful?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues

I just visited the [Review Queues page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/), and noticed a part of the page that shows recent reviewers.

[image: recent reviewers]

I stopped and thought for some time for how people use this information for anything useful. I came up with nothing, really.

So, should we discuss and come up with something more useful to use that space in the page? Or is there anything people have been doing with that information that it should still be there?

If we don't have anything more useful for it and we decide to remove it for better performance for the site? Is it worth it?

Just curious.

Comment: It hints that there's a way to see the number of reviews that *any* user has done in *any* review queue (not just those in the leaderboards). [This Meta Stack Exchange post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214527/284827) gives more details.

Comment: "*If we don't have anything more useful for it and we decide to remove it for better performance for the site? Is it worth it?*" does performance right now *suffer* because this information is included? Page doesn't seem to load any slower for me, compared with other pages.

Comment: I feel this is a valid question, but only insomuch as we can come up with some other stat that's more useful to replace it. Personally, I feel like "items left in the queue" is the most important queue stat, and that's already on the left... maybe something about how many reviews have been completed today? But I'm not sure that'd be any more useful than the reviewer avatars are currently.

Comment: What even is the point of this post? As if SE will implement the feature, if anyone even determines what it should be??

Comment: That can be a good feature request but yes, what should be here ? If you find nothing else, stay with this seems the best solution.

Comment: They've already got enough on their plate trying to fix all the issues with the new layouts...

Comment: Maybe an overview of outcome stats instead of the avatars? Like how many: accepts, rejects, mod reviews (maybe a percentage as well), etc. There is a lot of real estate to fit some useful stats. There is a concern, though, that pulling those stats comes with a performance penalty.

Answer (score 3):

There are so many reviewers on Stack Overflow that I don't find this section very useful either. But it's not actively harmful (why would "select top 5" be a problem for performance?), so there's no compelling reason to remove it.

But that's only on Stack Overflow. On other sites, where there are often very few reviewers, this part of the page provides essential information not conveniently found anywhere else. Are there a variety of users or just a few? Are moderators reviewing too often? Does the list look the same after several days even when more posts need review? These are all things I look for on this page on other sites and there's just no easy way to find out at a glance without these lists.

It's also a little cool to see your avatar on the list when you've just reviewed something. That's true on all sites.

Comment: I agree that these lists are useful on smaller sites to get an idea of which people are frequent reviewers. However, having a feature that is useful on smaller sites and not on SO does not sound like something SE would do. So maybe there are other (historical) reasons for presenting this information?